# How can I insert data from an Access form into a sql table using VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Here is what I have, I'm trying to take fields from an Access form (data comes from one linked sql table) and insert them into another linked sql table:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Expense_Projection] ([StatusID],[TravellerUFID],[Email]) " & _
          VALUES(" & Me.StatusID & ", " Me.TravellerUFID & ", " Me.SubmitterUFID & ", " Me.email & ")
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
```

But I am getting this error

```
Compile error: Sub or Function not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are just missing some double quotes:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Expense_Projection] ([StatusID],[TravellerUFID],[Email]) " & _
"VALUES(" & Me.StatusID & ", " Me.TravellerUFID & ", " Me.SubmitterUFID & ", """ & Me.email & """)"
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
```

You can try to print the contents of StrSQL and check the query before running it:

```
Debug.Print StrSQL
```

but I prefer not to create SQL strings with concatenated values (what happens if Me.StravellerUFID contains a double quote?)

I would suggest you to insert data using DAO:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_Expense_Projection")
rs.AddNew
rs!StatusID = Me.StatusID
rs!TravellerUFID = Me.TravellerUFID
' ...other fields
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Comment: There is a lot to be said for parameters. They scale better if you need to change the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some ampersands missing in the SQL-String:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO [dbo_Expense_Projection] ([StatusID],[TravellerUFID],[Email]) " & _
          "VALUES(" & Me!StatusID & ", " & Me!TravellerUFID & ", " & Me!SubmitterUFID & ", """ & Me!email & """)"
```

And I think you should use exclamation mark between "Me" and fieldname. But I do not want to argue with the experts here about that... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working:

```
Dim StrSQL As String

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_Expense_Projection (StatusID,TravellerUFID,Email) 
          VALUES('" & Form!StatusID & "','" & Form!TravellerUFID & "','" & Form!Email & "')"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```